# Array merge anomaly

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, array-merge

I don't understand why the below solution doesn't return the anticipated result.

Use case:
nums1: [1,2,3,0,0,0],
nums2: [2,5,6],
m:3,
n:3

Expected result: [1,2,2,3,5,6], reality [1,2,2,3,0,0]

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/

```py
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :type n: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while i+j <= m+n:
            if nums1[i] < nums2[j]:
                i+=1
            else:
                temp = nums2[j]
                nums1[i+j+1 : i+j+m+1] = nums1[i+j : i+j+m]
                nums1[i+j] = temp
                j +=1 
        return nums1
```

Algorithm:

1. Initialize i and j to 0
2. Check if nums1[i] < nums2[j]
3. 1. If 2: keep nums1[i] as is and increment i.
   2. If not 2: shift non zero nums1 values by an index of 1 and increment j.
4. return nums1

Yet, perplexingly, this works as intended until the last two remaining elements of nums2 need to be visited. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

A viable option is to go backwards from the right to the left in this case, `i = m - 1` and `j = n - 1`, because the first array `nums1` is half filled from the left, and after merging, it will be completely filled with the sorted output. The function will not return a new array.

```
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :type n: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
        i = m - 1
        j = n - 1
        while j >= 0:
            if i < 0:
                nums1[:j+1] = nums2[:j+1]
                break
            if nums1[i] > nums2[j]:
                nums1[i+j+1] = nums1[i]
                i -= 1
            else:
                nums1[i+j+1] = nums2[j]
                j -= 1
```

Input: `nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]`, `m = 3`, `nums2 = [2,5,6]`, `n = 3`

Output: `[1,2,2,3,5,6]`

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy, I edited to account for some corner cases, it is now accepted at LeetCode. It is also 95% faster than previous submissions.

Comment: *"It is also 95% faster than previous submissions."* - Perhaps it is. Although I estimate that 99% of such claims are wrong :-P (Since LeetCode is super bad at measuring and soooo many people act as if it weren't, so I never trust such claims unless people demonstrate that they measured properly.)